# Otaining bug fixes for Delphi

Tags: delphi

Does anyone know how (if) I can obtain bug fixes for Delphi for known, fixed bugs (specifically [QC report #125506](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=125506) relating to indexes in Clientdatasets)

I understand that it has been fixed in XE7 but I object(!!!) to paying £1,000+ to update from XE6 to XE7 when I have only had XE6 for a matter of months, I have spent the time identifying the bug and the ONLY reason I have for moving from XE6 to XE7 is to fix the bug (rant over)!

Comment: I think you have to talk to Embarcadero. Submit an official support ticket. I don't hold up much hope that you will get anywhere though. If you have the source code for the faulty code then you could fix the problem, but I suspect that this may be part of the source code that Emba keep hidden.

Comment: Your best hope are thah Andy will put it in his Fix pack:
http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/ide-tools/ide-fix-pack/

As fat as I know it is not there, but ask him.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for posting this as an "answer" but there are a few things worth mentioning that won't fit comfortably in a comment (or two).

As you've probably gathered, the "Resolution comments" on QC #125506 don't say anything useful, in particular about what was changed or where e.g. in DBClient.Pas or Midas.Dll.  I've just run Beyond Compare on the sources of DBClient.Pas in XE6 & XE7, and the changes are minimal:  The declaration of TCustomClientDataSet has had a local class declaration of "TPersistDataPacket" added to it and there are a few consequential changes, but whether they bear on QC #125506 is impossible to say.  I wondered about quoting the changes here, but decided not to in view of possible copyright or T&C problems.

The versions of MidasLib.Pas in XE6 and XE7 are identical, but the size of the 32-bit release build of MidasLib.Dcu has increased marginally, from 241447 to 241646 bytes.  Oddly, Midas.Dll has actually reduced in size, from 451960 to 437632 bytes.

A couple of obvious suggestions:

1. I'm not sure if the trial version of XE7 includes the Datasnap stuff, but in view of the expense, it would definitely be worth "trying before you buy" if you can manage it.  If it doesn't include Datasnap, you might nevertheless see if you can get hold of a copy of the XE7 Midas.Dll - once upon a time Borland-as-was was quite liberal in allowing the latest Midas.Dll to be used with earlier versions.  Might be worthwhile asking about both these points on the EMBA newgroups.
2. In QC #125506, the reporter seems to have run into the problem when using the CDS IndexFieldNames property.  If that's how your getting it, have you tried defining a persistent IndexDef instead?  The following code works for me (tested on the Authors table of the Sql Server Pubs demo database).

Dynamically adding/using an IndexDef.

```
procedure TDefaultForm.AddIndex(AFieldName: String; CaseInsensitive: Boolean);
var
  AIndexDef : TIndexDef;
  AIndexName : String;
  Options : TIndexOptions;
  BM : TBookmark;
begin
  if CDS1.IndexDefs.GetIndexForFields(AFieldName, CaseInsensitive) = Nil then begin
    BM := CDS1.GetBookmark;
    try
      CDS1.DisableControls;
      AIndexName := 'By' + AFieldName;
      Options := [];
      if CaseInsensitive then
        Options := Options + [ixCaseInsensitive];
      AIndexDef := TIndexDef.Create(CDS1.IndexDefs, AIndexName, AFieldName, Options);
      CDS1.IndexName := AIndexName;
    finally
      CDS1.GotoBookmark(BM);
      CDS1.FreeBookmark(BM);
      CDS1.EnableControls;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TDefaultForm.btnAddClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AddIndex('au_lname', True);
end;
```

Comment: The trial version of Delphi is similar to an Enterprise SKU.

Comment: @UweRaabe:  Thanks - I had a feeling it might be, but wasn't sure to what extent - if at all - the trial version might have restricted functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions - I will give them a go. BTW, I was the reporter for QC #125506 - I can't use persistent IndexDefs because they are indexes created at runtime in response to user selections (mainly sorting grids)

Comment: Well done for submitting the QC.  " I can't use persistent IndexDefs because ..."  Oh?  I've added a bit of code to my answer that seems to work fine for me.